# Reading from CAN bus of a Chevrolet Cruze using an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, can, obd

I'm using the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno), [CAN bus shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10039), and [OBDII to DB9 Cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10087) using  [their provided libraries](http://www.skpang.co.uk/catalog/arduino-canbus-shield-with-usd-card-holder-p-706.html). I was only able to initialize it.

**Readings:**

*While connected to the car:*

- CAN-High: 2.7 V - 3.0 V
- CAN-Low: 2.4 V - 2.7 V

*While not connected to the car:*

- CAN-High: ~2.4 V
- CAN-Low: ~2.5 V

Note: in both cases the Arduino is connected to my PC via USB (for debugging).

Sample code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   //Software serial port
#include <Canbus.h>

#define CBRxD 5  // CAN BUS RX
#define CBTxD 4  // TX

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1

char buffer[512];  //Data will be temporarily stored to this buffer before being written to the file
char tempbuf[15];
char lat_str[14];
char lon_str[14];

int LED2 = 7;
int LED3 = 8;

boolean scan = true;

SoftwareSerial canbusSerial(CBRxD, CBTxD);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    canbusSerial.begin(4800);
    pinMode(0, INPUT);
    pinMode(BTTxD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);

    setupCanbus();
}

void loop() {
    char recvChar;
    if (canbusSerial.available()) {  // Check if there's any data sent from the remote CAN bus shield
        recvChar = canbusSerial.read();
        Serial.print("CAN: "+recvChar);
    }

    if (scan) {
        digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);

        if(Canbus.ecu_req(ENGINE_RPM,buffer) == 1) {       /* Request for engine RPM */
            Serial.println(buffer);                        /* Display data on Serial Monitor */
        }
        Serial.println(buffer);

        if(Canbus.ecu_req(VEHICLE_SPEED,buffer) == 1) {
            Serial.println(buffer);
        }Serial.println(buffer);

        if(Canbus.ecu_req(ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP,buffer) == 1) {
            Serial.print(buffer);
        }Serial.println(buffer);

        if(Canbus.ecu_req(THROTTLE,buffer) == 1) {
            Serial.println(buffer);
        }
        Serial.println(buffer);
        //  Canbus.ecu_req(O2_VOLTAGE,buffer);

        digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
        delay(100);
    }
}

void setupCanbus() {
    while (!Canbus.init(CANSPEED_250)) {
        Serial.println("CAN Init");
    }
    Serial.println("CAN Init OK");
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: What output do you get on the serial terminal?

Comment: Also, if you have a multimeter, switch it to ohms and measure the resistance across the CANH and CANL pins. Check out your pinout [here](http://pinoutsguide.com/CarElectronics/gm_car_obd_ii_pinout.shtml). Should be pins 6 and 14. You may need to terminate the connection with a 120ohm resistor if it's not already terminated.

Comment: first thing>> "CAN INIT OK". Then empty lines (printing empty buffer array)

Comment: The resistance measured across CANH and CANL is 38.4 Kohm, and across CANL and CANH is 79.8 Kohm. (not sure if that's possible)

Comment: yes, it checked it before it is 6 and 14, but how do i know it's terminated, if not how do i terminate it?

Answer (score 3):

I think your car is similiar to [Opel Astra J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opel_Astra#Astra_J_.282009.E2.80.93present.29). It uses [GMLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMLAN) which is a low- speed CAN bus (33 kbit/s).

I've been able to read and send CAN data with the same hardware.

I had to connect CAN-H and CAN-L respectively to the *SW-LS-CAN* pin and to ground, according to the second table of page *[General Motors (GM) OBD II diagnostic interface pinout](http://pinoutsguide.com/CarElectronics/gm_car_obd_ii_pinout.shtml)*.

I used the code in https://github.com/Afterglow/arduino-gmlan.

Tell me if this works.

Comment: I was able to connect to my Chevrolet Cruze, with the GMLAN at 33.3Kbps. I used the same pins that you've mentioned, but not the code. I used the mcp_can library.

Answer (score 0):

Their example code has

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial = SoftwareSerial(4, 5);
```

You have

```
SoftwareSerial canbusSerial(CBRxD, CBTxD);
```

Which translates to the opposite pin order

```
SoftwareSerial canbusSerial(5, 4);
```

Perhaps switching `CBRxD` and `CBTxD` would work.

Comment: i hope it works, i'll try as soon as i have access to the car. Should i be getting any different response on the serial monitor although not connected to the car?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't fix it.

Comment: Did the example code with the shield work?

Comment: nothing has changed, i get `CAN Init OK`, and then all empty lines (empty buffer)

Comment: Is the speed correct? In their code they init with `CANSPEED_500`

Comment: i tried all three (500, 250, 125)